# Dynamics CRM [WebAPI] OData, There is no "OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue" information in $Expand

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Please refer to the image.

[image]

new_p_currency is option set

```
type: "new_quot_detailses",
options: "?$select=new_name,new_d_tax,new_d_totalprice,new_f_price,new_i_qty,new_txt_standard,new_txt_unitdesc,new_txt_unitgroup,new_txt_unittitle" +
         "&$expand=new_l_quot,new_l_product($select=new_name,new_d_unitprice,new_p_currency,new_p_type,new_txt_unitcode,new_txt_unitdesc,new_txt_unitgroup,new_txt_unittype)" +
         "&$filter=_new_l_quot_value eq " + quotguid,
extraHeaders: {
         "Prefer": "odata.include-annotations=*"
},
```

There is no "`OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue`" information in $Expand.

Is there a workaround available?

help!!

Answer (score 0):

add this to the http header when you are doing the webapi call:

```
"Prefer", 'odata.include-annotations="*"'
```